# deploy WCF service with public IP

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I created a WCF application that must be accessible on internet. 
I deployed this application on a WS2008 R2 server with IIS. This server have a private IP but I configure NAT redirection on port 35000.

When I put the correct URI (with public IP) on a web browser, I can show the service page correctly but the link generated by IIS to show WSDL is not correct, I have the server name instead of public IP like this :

```
http://serverName:35000/ServiceName.svc?wsdl
```

instead of

```
http://publicIP:35000/ServiceName.svc?wsdl
```

so when I click on the link, the server name can't be resolve.

In my web.config file, I add an endpoint with the correct IP, and I also try to add an identity tag and DNS tag with the public IP but it doesn't work.

This is my web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="myNamespace.ServiceName.svc">
        <endpoint address="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:35000/myNamespace/ServiceName/" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="myNamespace.IServiceName">
          <identity>
            <dns value="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is the end of WSDL :

```
<wsdl:service name="ServiceName">
  <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceName" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IServiceName">
<soap:address location="http://serverName:35000/ServiceName.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I also try in IIS to add the public IP as hostname but I obtain an error.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the mex endpoint :

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

and it works perfectly...